# C programming ++ operator

Tags: c, post-increment

Why does this code always produce `x=2`?

```
unsigned int x = 0;
x++ || x++ || x++ || x++ || ........;
printf("%d\n",x);
```

Comment: Smells like someone's homework.

Comment: Still a good question, i think. In the first moment, i thought it's undefined behavior. But actually it is not since `||` is a sequence point between the left and right sides.

Comment: FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Answer (score 30, accepted):

the 1st `x++` changes x to 1 and returns 0
the 2nd `x++` changes x to 2 and returns 1

at which point the or short circuits, returns true, and leaves x at 2.

Comment: Incidentally:

unsigned int x = 0;
++x || ++x || ++x || ++x || ........;
printf("%d\n",x);

would give 1 as the first ++x would change x to 1 and return x, short-circuiting happens and nothing more is done.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure this is undefined behavior. Your description of why it would yield 2 is right, but I don't believe it's guaranteed to work that way — you're not supposed to change a variable more than once in a statement The variable could not be incremented until after the whole expression is finished, in which case `x` would always appear to be 0.

Comment: @Chuck: It's defined because `||` acts as a sequence point. (6.5.14/4 in the C99 standard.)

Comment: Cobbal, to make it clearer, you should write your answer as, returns 0 and then changes x to 1. Making it clearing that the expression is incremented post Boolean evaluation.

Comment: @James McMahon, To my knowledge, when it's incremented isn't defined, just what it returns and what it does to x.

Comment: @Jamesdin, @cobbal is correct. The thing that isn't defined is when the increment happens, only what order the return statements happen is defined.

So, for example, x = 1; x ++ && x ++ && x ++ && ... is undefined by the spec. because it could be that  x gets incremented from 1 to 2 many many times, or it could be that each time it gets incremented again, or several other cases...

Comment: @Brian: `&&` and `||` are sequence points; the expression on the left is fully evaluated before the expression on the right is even considered (or discarded, in the case of short-circuiting).  This is well-defined behavior.  Compare to `,` and `;` which are also sequence points.

Comment: @Brian, that's not undefined. All increments are done. And all increments happen one after each other. Leaving `x` with value `1 + N` with `N` being the count of operands. Of course, if you have written more than `UINT_MAX` operands, all operands after operand `UINT_MAX + 1` are not executed anymore since that one evaluates to `0`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Didn't know that `||` counted as a sequence point.

Comment: For the record, sequence points occur at the end of a full expression (initializer, expression statement, the expression in a return statement, and control expressions in conditional, iterative, or switch statements), after the first operand of `&&`, `||`, `?:`, or the comma operator, and after the evaluation of the arguments and function expression in a function call.

Answer (score 11):

x++ || x++ || x++ || x++ || ........;

- First x++ evaluates to 0 first for the conditional check, followed by an increment. So, first condition fails, but x gets incremented to 1.
- Now the second x++ gets evaluated, which evaluates to 1 for the conditional check, and x gets incremented to 2. Since expression evaluates to 1 (true), there's no need to go further.

Answer (score 9):

Because of [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit_(programming)) in boolean expression evaluation and because `||` is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in C and C++.

Comment: || is a sequence point, as the page you linked to mentions. So this is not undefined behaviour.

Comment: The `||` operator introduces a sequence point, so the expression is not undefined.

Answer (score 5):

`||` short-circuits. Evaluated from left, when a true value is found (non-zero) it stops evaluating, since the expression now is true and never can be false again.

First `x++` evaluates to 0 (since it's post-increment), second to 1 which is true, and presto, you're done!

Answer (score 2):

When you're evaluating "a || b || c || d || e || ..." you can stop evaluating at the first non-zero value you find.

The first "x++" evaluates to 0, and increments x to 1, and evaluating the expression continues.  The second x++ is evaluated to 1, increments x to 2, and at that point, you need not look at the rest of the OR statement to know that it's going to be true, so you stop.

Comment: To be precise, you do stop evaluating at the first non-zero value you find.

Answer (score 1):

Because logical OR short-circuits when a true is found.

So the first x++ returns 0 (false) because it is post-increment.  (x = 1)
The second x++ returns 1 (true) - short-circuits.  (x = 2)

Prints x = 2;

Answer (score 1):

Because of early out evaluation of comparisons.

This is the equivalent of

```
 0++ | 1++
```

The compiler quits comparing as soon as x==1, then it post increments, making x==2

Answer (score 1):

Because the first "x++ || x++" evaluates to "true" (meaning it is non zero because "0 || 1" is true.  Since they are all logical OR operators the rest of the OR operations are ignored.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator evaluates the left-hand expression, and if it is 0 (false), then it will evaluate the right-hand expression.  If the left hand side is not 0, then it will not evaluate the right hand side at all.

In the expression `x++ || x++ || x++ || ...`, the first `x++` is evaluated; it evaluates to 0, and x is incremented to 1.  The second `x++` is evaluated; it evaluates to 1, and x is incremented to 2.  Since the second `x++` evaluated to a non-zero value, none of the remaining `x++` expressions are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

<del>trying replacing `||` with `|`.--</del>

It is the short circuiting of logical operators.

It's the same reason when you do

```
if (returns_true() || returns_true()){ }
```

`returns_true` will only get called once.

Comment: Since `||` is a sequence point and `|` isn't, if you replace `||` with `|`, you'll be invoking undefined behavior, and that won't really tell you anything.